# BigQuery ML Evaluation metrics (nDCG = 1)

Tags: google-bigquery, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am using BigQuery ML to train a matrix factorization model for recommending products to customers based on their transaction history.

My problem is that the **nDCG (calculated by google) is 1**, and I don't know why. This is obviously wrong.
I had the theory that previously bought products have the highest prediction rating and therefore "clutter" the prediction with perfect ratings, resulting in a perfect nDCG.
But that is not the case, often a new product is at 4th or 6th place.

Also, I couldn't find anything in the [google docu](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-evaluate) about how the nDCG is calculated, to explain the behaviour.
I hope somebody can explain that behaviour or help me fix the underlying problem.

### Input data

The input data is based on implicit feedback and the rating is binarily encoded.

```
1 -> bought the product previously
0 -> no previous transaction
```

The input data only consists of a *cust prod* combination that exists in the transaction history.
So every input has a rating of **1**.
It looks like that and has 80,3M rows:

```
| cust_code |   prod_code | rating |
| --------- | ----------- | ------ |
| CUST0000000001 | PRD0900001 | 1 |
| CUST0000000001 | PRD0900027 | 1 |
| CUST0000000009 | PRD0900008 | 1 |
| CUST0000000009 | PRD0900034 | 1 |
```

### Query

The query to train the model:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `my_model`
    OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE = 'MATRIX_FACTORIZATION',
        FEEDBACK_TYPE = 'IMPLICIT',
        USER_COL = "cust_code",
        ITEM_COL = "prod_code",
        RATING_COL = "rating",
        DATA_SPLIT_METHOD = 'AUTO_SPLIT') AS 
    SELECT
      cust_code,
      prod_code,
      rating,
    FROM
      `project_id.dataset.source_table`
```

Comment: What are the results from the other metrics? How sparse is your input table?

Comment: @LisaYin, thanks for reaching out. The other metrics calculated by Google were:
Mean average precision = 0,1659
Mean square error = 0,0068
Average rank = 0,4649 

About the input data, I don't know how to express how sparse a table is, but  I would say it was sparse. I had a lot of customers buying only a couple of items.

Comment: Can you file a bug report with a job id and we can take a closer look? There may be a bug in the calculation. Thank you!

Comment: This may take a while because the project finished by now, and I have to recreate it. But I will let you know, when I filed the bug report :)